# Remotely stop-process multiple names using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How can I kill all Powershell script in a remote computer that has caused hangs or running out of memory?

```
Get-Process -Name 'conhost', 'PowerShell' -ComputerName 'AD-DC01' | Measure-Object
returns 1000+ process.

Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  501 conhost                   {System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost), System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost), System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost), System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost)...}                                                                      
  505 powershell                {System.Diagnostics.Process (powershell), System.Diagnostics.Process (powershell), System.Diagnostics.Process (powershell), System.Diagnostics.Process (powershell)...}
```

I cannot pipe that result above into **Stop-Process** ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-7)) as it throws an error:

```
Stop-Process : Cannot stop process "conhost (3380)" because of the following error: Feature is not supported for remote machines.
At line:1 char:72
+ ... ame 'conhost', 'PowerShell' -ComputerName 'AD-DC01' | Stop-Process
+                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Diagnostics.Process (conhost):Process) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopProcess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

Comment: You could still use `Invoke-Command` to remotely stop the processes you want.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, that does make sense.
Should I call the Powershell.exe with parameter in the Script block or just Stop-Process cmdlet?

Comment: You are a **Senior** Systems Engineer: Would it hurt you when you just tried and figure out by yourself? That's the way an engineer usually acts.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WMI with the Cim cmdlets to do it.  Something like:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName ServerName -ClassName win32_Process -Filter "NAME = 'PowerShell.exe' OR NAME = 'conhost.exe'" | 
Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Terminate
```

You may want to play with the filter though.

Also, you can invoke directly without using `Get-CimInstance` First

```
Invoke-CimMethod -ComputerName ServerName -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'powershell.exe' OR Name = 'conhost.exe'" -MethodName Terminate
```

If you still want to use remoting, and to answer your previous question you don't need to call PowerShell when remoting, it would look something like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Name 'conhost', 'PowerShell' -ComputerName 'AD-DC01' | Stop-Process }
```

Comment: Wow, @Steven, many thanks for your great assistance. It works great.
I appreciate your assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

You snippet does not work because you are first actaully getting process on the remote computer and piping them to stop-process in local computer. Instead use `invoke-command` as @Olaf

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName AD-DC01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Name 'conhost', 'PowerShell' | Stop-Process}
```

you might have to use the `-Authentication Kerberos` option to gain rights to the remote computer. Also you can use `psexec` along with `taskkill`.

Comment: I'm not sure other than to say the cmdlet can't do it, and neither can the returned `[System.Diagnostics.Process]`object.  If you try to run the Kill method it will return the same exception.  `Get/Stop-Service` are similar at least in Windows PowerShell, but the `[ServiceController] ` object's Stop/Start... methods can in fact work against remote machines.